# Powershell Logging_Functions Causing Unexplained Error

Tags: powershell, logging

I managed to get rid of the message by changing line 53 to :

`New-Item -Path $sFullPath -ItemType File -Force`

Which also allows removal of the `Test-Path` above this (thanks to -Force), But I don't understand why New-Item would try to create a new folder when `-ItemType File` has been specified, AND the path and name have both been provided ...

---

I am trying to use `Logging_Functions.ps1` Module which I got [here](http://9to5it.com/powershell-logging-function-library/).

This is how I am calling it:

```
."\\DC1\NETLOGON\PSSubs\Logging_Functions.ps1"

Log-Start -LogPath "\\DC1\NETLOGON\PSSubs" -LogName "Test_Log.log" -ScriptVersion "1.5"
```

As per the documentation. However, when running the above I am seeing this annoying message:

> New-Item : The file '\DC1\NETLOGON\PSSubs' already exists.
>   At \DC1\NETLOGON\PSSubs\Logging_Functions.ps1:53 char:5
>   +     New-Item -Path $LogPath -Value $LogName -ItemType File
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (\DC1\NETLOGON\PSSubs:String) [New-Item], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Even though this error appears, the file is created and I have no idea why it is complaining about the folder name, as line 53 is not asking it to create the folder.

When I run **the exact same line** inside the actual `Logging_Functions.ps1` file, it works without error. I've included the `Log-Start` function below (which I altered slightly on line 53 to replace `-Value` with `-Name` as this seems correct):

```
Function Log-Start{    
  [CmdletBinding()]

  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$LogPath, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$LogName, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ScriptVersion
    )

  Process{
    $sFullPath = $LogPath + "\" + $LogName

    #Check if file exists and delete if it does
    If((Test-Path -Path $sFullPath)){
      Remove-Item -Path $sFullPath -Force
    }

    #Create file and start logging
    New-Item -Path $LogPath -Name $LogName -ItemType File

    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value "***************************************************************************************************"
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value "Started processing at [$([DateTime]::Now)]."
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value "***************************************************************************************************"
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value ""
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value "Running script version [$ScriptVersion]."
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value ""
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value "***************************************************************************************************"
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value ""

    #Write to screen for debug mode
    Write-Debug "***************************************************************************************************"
    Write-Debug "Started processing at [$([DateTime]::Now)]."
    Write-Debug "***************************************************************************************************"
    Write-Debug ""
    Write-Debug "Running script version [$ScriptVersion]."
    Write-Debug ""
    Write-Debug "***************************************************************************************************"
    Write-Debug ""
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help explain what the difference is here? Why would one way cause an error and not the other, when they are supposedly doing the exact same thing? Thanks!

Comment: That does seem odd at first glance. It _should_ work the same. What PowerShell version are you running so I can try to replicate this?

Comment: @Matt `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

>Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1

Answer (score 1):

You can change all of this:

```
#Check if file exists and delete if it does
If((Test-Path -Path $sFullPath)){
  Remove-Item -Path $sFullPath -Force
}

#Create file and start logging
New-Item -Path $LogPath -Name $LogName -ItemType File
```

To the following one liner, as the `-Force` will overwrite any file that already exists:

```
New-Item -Path $sFullPath -ItemType File -Force
```

Comment: Yes, the op is aware of this but he is not asking for this as a fix. This is good extra information though.